# Dealing with bad email, possibly migrating to Gmail

Tags: email

I'm the tech guy for a start-up company, and our email situation is not good.  It appears that our host provider is having trouble with their outgoing email servers getting blacklisted for spam, so it's a crap shoot as to whether any of our messages get received.

Of the partners, I'm the most qualified to do something about this, but this is outside my area of expertise -- I'm more of a software developer.  So I'm here looking for advice/guidance.

The long term solution is to migrate to a host provider that's less terrible (this is not my only problem with them), but for the short term, that's not an option.  (The majority partner and I don't see eye-to-eye on who our next provider ought to be.)

Working with the provider to deal with the problem doesn't seem to be an option, either.  I've tried, but if they care that they have multiple mail servers being blacklisted for spam, they're doing a good job of concealing it from me.

It occurred to me that Gmail might be a solution; I've worked for other startups that had "myaccount@ourcompany.com" set up as Gmail accounts.  I see that there are resources out there describing how to get this set up, but I don't know how the existing accounts complicate the issue.  Would I have to create entirely new accounts for use under Gmail, or could I migrate the existing accounts?  Is there something clever I can do to migrate my existing IMAP account, or would I just have to accept that messages from before the switch-over date are only accessible via my local email client?

My thanks in advance for any advice people can offer or resources people can point me towards that will help me get this situation resolved.

Comment: I'm not entirely certain this in on-topic on ServerFault, it might be better placed here http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @EightBitTony:  49 views and 1 answer suggest you may be correct.  :-)  I'll try my luck there too, thanks.

Comment: It's early, not many folk on yet, and cross-posting usually gets ugly, if you want to ask over there I suggest you delete the question from here, or, moderators can move them, if you flag it I think (if the question gets moved, the answer will go with it).  I'll vote to close, but I can't automatically suggest webmasters.SE (it's not on the list).

Comment: I'll leave it here for now then, but I shan't be surprised if the moderators move it elsewhere.

Comment: Part of the problem here is that you are asking for `So I'm here looking for advice/guidance`.  SF strongly prefers far more concrete questions.  This is a Q&A site, not a forum, we prefer specific questions which should potentially have one good answer.

Comment: I suggest that you change your question to "how do I migrate mail from service X to Gmail".

Answer (score 0):

Ive been using google apps for a while now and its awesome.

Transferring email is seamless from these servers

- Microsoft® Exchange (2003 or 2007)
- IBM Lotus Notes®
- Groupwise®
- Another IMAP server (eg, Novelle® or Gmail)

Its a simple checkbox during setup along with credentials so google can DL the email

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps is good, Office 365 is good.

If you want it in-house, you can buy a server from Dell with Small Business Server already on it: that'll do mail, SharePoint and so on.

You just follow the instructions. I imagine you could set up SBS with your eyes closed.

It's one initial cost but it won't have an ongoing, monthly charge - depends on what your finance guy prefers.

:)